# Enumerating through background workers

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, enumeration

Is there a way to enumerate through all background workers?  Currently, I've written a small method that I add to as I create new workers.  Only one worker should run at a time, so the check method is:

```
    private bool CheckForWorkers()  // returns true if any background workers are currently running
    {
        bool ret = false;

        if (bgWorkerFoo.IsBusy || bgWorkerMeh.IsBusy || bgWorkerHmpf.IsBusy || bgWorkerWorkyWorky.IsBusy || bgWorkerOMGStahp.IsBusy)
        {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

At the time a button is clicked that would start a worker, the click method does this:

```
        if (CheckForWorkers())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File generation already in progress.  Please wait.", "Message");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            bgWorkerFoo.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

I'd like to clean up my CheckForWorkers() method so that I don't need to add to it anytime a new worker is created for a different task, but I can't seem to find any way to run through each worker associated with the app. Maybe there isn't a way?  Do all of the workers exist (are instantiated) prior to being used?

Comment: Don't throw "you did something stoopid" message boxes into the user's face.   It is your job to take care of this, disable the button.

Comment: Hans, obviously all situations are different. In this case there are tabs each with a work type. I could disable all the buttons, and probably will, but it's not important at the moment. I always code to my user base, which in this case are my fellow QA Testers and Analysts, and my companies support staff. Since it's an internal tool, I'm not quite as focused on UI friendliness at the moment. That can all come later. Functionality is currently king.

Comment: Aside from which, it's possible down the road that I'll allow multiple workers to run in separate threads, but I have a lot of stuff that's not terribly thread safe, including a global Dictionary<> that holds configuration information based on option selections. Thread safe collections are still fairly new to me.

Comment: what does LoS stand for btw ??  @JesseWilliams

Comment: Line of Sight, the field of view of a player in a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something similar to this?

```
Worker[] Workers => new[] { bgWorkerFoo, bgWorkerMeh, bgWorkerHmpf, bgWorkerWorkyWorky, bgWorkerOMGStahp };
private bool CheckForWorkers() 
{
    return Workers.Any(w => w != null && w.IsBusy);
}
```

It's likely you'll need to refer to the collection of workers in the future as well, so it makes sense to put them into a collection anyway

Or, for non-C#6 syntax, a bit uglier:

```
private Worker[] Workers { get { return new[] { bgWorkerFoo, bgWorkerMeh, bgWorkerHmpf, bgWorkerWorkyWorky, bgWorkerOMGStahp }; } }
private bool CheckForWorkers() 
{
    return Workers.Any(w => w != null && w.IsBusy);
}
```

To dynamically get all fields/properties in your class, you can do this:

```
private IEnumerable<Worker> GetWorkers()
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
    var fields = GetType().GetFields(flags);
    var fieldValues = fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).OfType<Worker>();

    var properties = GetType().GetProperties(flags);
    var propertyValues = properties.Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).OfType<Worker>();

    return fieldValues.Concat(propertyValues).Where(w => w != null);
}

private bool CheckForWorkers() 
{
    return GetWorkers().Any(w => w.IsBusy);
}
```

Might be a good idea to cache `GetWorkers()`, but it depends on your use-case.

Comment: Hmmm, I might look at trying this method. Will creating the Worker array interfere with, or need to replace, their instantiation elsewhere such as in the form code?

Comment: Actually, that still doesn't resolve the primary question - iterating through all background workers programmatically so that I don't need to keep a list.  Or, at a minimum, creating the array programmatically from all worker objects that are generated in the Form1.Designer.cs.  Is that possible?

Comment: @JesseWilliams Not at all, it's lazily executed, so it will only create the array when you check the workers. As for dynamically picking up the workers, give me a moment, I'll update my post

Comment: That's pretty slick.  Unfortunately, it's failing to compile on: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.Container' to type 'System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker'` in `CheckForWorkers()`

Comment: Sorry, my bad - it should be `OfType<>` not `Cast<>`

Comment: Ah, ok - I should've seen that.  I looked at it and shrugged it off.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest an alternative approach that may be appealing. The Microsoft Reactive Framework introduced a a lot of very useful functionality for dealing with concurrency and threads. Primarily the framework is used to deal with event sources in terms of `IObservable<T>`, but the framework also provides a lot of schedulers for dealing with processing on different threads.

One of the schedulers is called `EventLoopScheduler` and this allows you to create a scheduler that runs on a background thread and only allows one operation to occur at any one time. Any thread can schedule tasks and tasks can be scheduled immediately or in the future, or even recurringly.

The key point here is that you **don't need to track** multiple background workers as it doesn't matter how many operations you schedule they'll **only run in series**.

When using Windows Forms you can use a scheduler called `ControlScheduler` that allows you to set up a scheduler that will post operations to the UI thread.

Once you have these two set up they become very easy to use.

Try this code:

```
var form1 = new Form();
var label1 = new Label();
label1.AutoSize = true;
form1.Controls.Add(label1);
form1.Show();

var background = new EventLoopScheduler();
var ui = new ControlScheduler(form1);

var someValue = -1;
background.Schedule(() =>
{
    var z = 42 * someValue;
    var bgTid = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    ui.Schedule(() =>
    {
        var uiTid = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        label1.Text = $"{z} calc on {bgTid} updated on {uiTid}";
    });
});
```

When I run this code I get this form showing on screen:

[image: form]

Clearly the calculation is correct and it can be seen that the thread ids are different.

You can even do more powerful things like this:

```
var booking =
    background.SchedulePeriodic(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), state =>
    {
        var copy = state;
        if (copy % 2 == 0)
        {
            ui.Schedule(() => label1.Text = copy.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            background.Schedule(() => ui.Schedule(() => label1.Text = "odd"));
        }
        return ++state;
    });

form1.FormClosing += (s, e) => booking.Dispose();
```

This code is creating a timer to run every second on the background thread. It uses the `state` variable to keep track of the number of times that it ran and updates the UI with the value of `state` when it is even, and otherwise, schedules on its own scheduler some code that will schedule on the UI to update `label1.Text` with the value `"odd"`. It can get quite sophisticated, but everything is serialized and synchronized for you. Since this created a timer there is a mechanism to shut the timer down and that is calling `booking.Dispose()`.

Of course, since this is using the Reactive Framework you could just use standard observables to do the above, like this:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), background)
    select n % 2 == 0 ? n.ToString() : "odd";

var booking = query.ObserveOn(ui).Subscribe(x => label1.Text = x);
```

Notice that the same schedulers are used.

Comment: That is... very nice. Sadly, I'm still a novice when it comes to .NET. This project has been my first baby steps into it. In fact, it started as a simple perl script and turned into a much more feature rich .NET project. However, when refactoring time comes, I'm coming back to look at this.

Comment: @JesseWilliams - I find background workers quite hard to work with. There's a lot of events and code flying everywhere. With the kind of approach I've presented you can do some amazing code in a nice neat compact block without the need to resort to complicated events. But it is a change in mindset. Good luck with it all.

Comment: Thanks for that. I "cheat" a lot with my background workers. Progress bars were a nightmare so I settled on marquee so at least the user has feedback that something is happening. I also don't use the cancel event do to some strangeness with some of the worker methods, instead on cancel I set a global variable that is checked in key locations which bail the process when true. It's not pretty, but it works well so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform the same task for a (potentially large or unlimited) number of variables, this likely means that they are "homogenious" in some manner and thus should probably be combined into some kind of a "registry" container instead.

E.g. I used to do something like this:

```
var thread = new BgWorker();
pool.Add(thread);
<...>
foreach (var thread in pool) {
    do_something();
}
```

The specific implementation of the registry van be anything, depending on what you need to do with your objects (e.g. a dictionary if you need to get a specific one in other scope than the one it was created in).